# Looking to ease workflow between RSS reader and Google Plus on iPad

Tags: ipad, rss, google

I'm a Google user, have been for years.  I've got a well established set of feeds in my Google Reader account.  I am also a Google Plus user.

I would like to have an easy workflow to go from reading things in Google Reader on the iPad to sharing them on Google Plus.  I don't see that happening with the Google Mobile interfaces presented on the iPad, so I come to you, the apple community, to ask if you've got a workflow figured out.

I am willing to entertain an alternate RSS reader than Google Reader.

I would like to view my RSS feeds on the iPad, and when I see something interesting, share it to Google Plus circles.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try out a native app (such as Reeder) with support for sharing through various services and which will eventually get support for Google+. Until then, perhaps a bookmarklet for Safari will do? See [here](https://www.google.se/search?q=Google%20plus%20bookmarklet&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 0):

You have to bear in mind that Google+, for all its polish and its growing community, is still in VERY early beta. Google is building connections between its properties like crazy, and one of those (they've promised!) will be between Reader and Plus.

I expect that eventually you'll be able to configure your Google account to automatically post things you share in Reader to your Plus feed. You probably won't need any changes to your rss reader at all.

For now I advise patience.